# Просмотр историй в телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как известно не так давно в телеграмм появились истории, возможно ли сделать их автоматический просмотр и проставление реакций(как например в ботах с просмотром историй в инстаграм)?

Желательно на Python